# SVN version control option in intellij

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Check out from Version control there is not option for SVN, how can I add it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into `File` -> `Settings` -> `Plugins`, search `Subversion Integration`, select it, and restart.